# How do you start GridDB client in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, griddb

I want to configure the database system https://github.com/griddb/griddb in Ruby. However, I am a relative new in this space. What are the starting points?

Comment: Well, the README file in the repository you linked to as well as the ones for the various language bindings linked from it would be a start. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I guess, i am wondering more about the potential obstacles. There seems to be different client version for Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preparations
Install SWIG as below.**

```
$ wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/pcre/files/pcre/8.39/pcre-8.39.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz pcre-8.39.tar.gz
$ cd pcre-8.39
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install

$ wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
$ cd swig-3.0.12
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

**Install Ruby and GridDB C Client.
If required, change INCLUDES_RUBY path in Makefile.
Set LIBRARY_PATH.**

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:<C client library file directory path>
```

**Build and Run**

1. Execute the command on project directory.

   $ make
2. Set the RUBYLIB variable for griddb griddb_ruby.so module files.

   $ export RUBYLIB=

**How to run sample**
GridDB Server need to be started in advance.

1. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:
2. The command to run sample

   $ ruby sample/sample.rb  
     
   -->['name01', false, 1, 'ABCDEFGHIJ' ]

**Function**

(available)

STRING, BOOL, BYTE, SHORT, INTEGER, LONG, FLOAT, DOUBLE, TIMESTAMP, BLOB type for GridDB
put single row, get row with key
normal query, aggregation with TQL
(not available)

Multi-Put/Get/Query (batch processing)
GEOMETRY, Array type for GridDB
timeseries compression
timeseries-specific function like gsAggregateTimeSeries, gsQueryByTimeSeriesSampling in C client
trigger, affinity

Please refer to the following files for more detailed information.

Ruby Client API Reference.

Comment: This answer was copied from https://github.com/griddb/ruby_client/blob/82a7b198ec0e5d1f616a559facd97a267a72cf76/README.md#quickstart without any changes. If when you quote external sources, it is customary (and legally required) to attribute your quote to the original author and source. Make sure to ALWAYS quote your sources.